# Override Default PUT/GET in spring data REST

Tags: spring

I'm using spring Data REST . (http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/rest)

My entity id contains "/" in it so trying to do a GET on my entity with entityId(e.g. "**thisisanentity/idwithaslashinIt**") as path parameter, spring is unable to fetch the correct entity. I get a HTTP 404 in both the cases below.

e.g. GET `/myentity/thisisanentity/idwithaslashinIt` HTTP 404(doesnt work with slash in entityId)

URL encoding doesent seem to help either.

i.e. GET `/myentity/thisisanentity%2FidwithaslashinIt` HTTP 404(doesnt work even with slash replaced with %2F)

Is there anyway to change default behaviour of path Parameters to sucessfully extract everything after "/myentity/" ?

Also how do i PUT(update) an entity since my entityId has slashes in it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which database you are accessing, but I think it may be a problem with the database, rather than the spring API. Try to escape the slash *before* storing it in the database. Also, try to access the entity from a browser/standalone client.

Comment: im using ms sql server. it is a legacy db, so i cannot escape the slash before storing. the data in the tables already have slash. its not a problem with the db, if i unit test the spring repository using junits it works, but if i come through the rest layer i get a 404.

Comment: Why do you access the database with REST, rather than using SQL?

Comment: @Bozho could you have a look at this question, thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032798/spring-soap-no-adapter-for-endpoint-error